# What is another word for "missing" in the context of missing someone who has passed away?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the deeply sad emotional state of missing someone who has passed away, such as parents?

Longing, yearning, pining, and aching don't feel like they would fit the bill.

Comment: The [SWR tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) asks you to provide a sample sentence. Doing so might help to clarify why you're asking about a verb's -ing form, whether you require a verb or not, why those other words don't fit the bill, etc.

Comment: If the word needn't be a present participle, I suggest nostalgia or nostalgic.

Answer (score 2):

**bereft** *adj* (2 of 2, OL&G)

> (of a person) sad and lonely, especially through someone's death or
> departure: "his death in 1990 left her bereft"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *mourning,* although I see no problem with *aching,* as you mentioned.

> the expression of deep sorrow for someone who has died [(Oxford Languages)](https://www.google.com/search?q=mourning+definition&oq=mourning+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.10833j0j4&client=ms-android-fi&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#:%7E:text=the%20expression%20of%20deep%20sorrow%20for%20someone%20who%20has%20died%2C)

Aching actually fits quite well:

> feeling intense or wistful sadness; sorrowful. [(Oxford Languages)](https://www.google.com/search?q=aching+definition&oq=aching+definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.6547j0j4&client=ms-android-fi&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#:%7E:text=feeling%20intense%20or%20wistful%20sadness%3B%20sorrowful.)